# Получение размера элемента при первом рендере

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Есть блок с текстом `<p className={'comment'}>{comment.text}</p>` и для него есть стили:

```
.comment
  overflow: hidden
  height: 34px
  font-size: 12px
  line-height: 1.5

  &:after
    position: absolute
    display: block
    width: 100%
    height: 30px
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #fff, transparent)
    content: ''
```

Если размер блока с текстом больше 34px (вешается псевдокласс `:after`), то нужно нужно отображать кнопку для раскрытия всего комментария.

P.s. считать кол-во символов не вариант, т.к. в тексте могут быть эмоджи или любые другие спецсимволы

Comment: так в чем проблема, после загрузки страницы возьмите высоту блока

Comment: как определить, что страница загружена в реакте?

Comment: react lifecycle hooks, если мне не изменеяет память вам нужен хук componentDidMount

Answer (score 0):

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node

Mожно еще `<div ref={setup}` и где функция `setup` получит элемент (div) на входе, возьмет размер и сделает `setState`.

Но, возможно, изображение заметно дернется. Идеально не сделать. Можно с начальным `visibility` поиграть.

Comment: еще можно `useLayoutEffect` попробовать

Comment: еще можно `ResizeObserver` попробовать